# Why do I keep getting a segmentation fault when I assign 'beginning' to variable currentPos of type memHead*?

Tags: c, malloc

Here is mymalloc.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "mymalloc.h"


static double memory[MAX_MEMORY]; //sets maximum memory sizeOfMem to 4096 bytes as defined in "mymalloc.h"
void *beginning = (memHead *)(memory); //initializes beginning of memory. Acts as a pointer to the beginning address of the list.


void *mymalloc(size_t size, char *file, int line) { //mymalloc function

    printf("mymalloc called\n");
    printf("Requested working bytes (reading MAX_MEMORY): %d bytes\n", MAX_MEMORY);

    memHead* currentPos = beginning; //sets the current position to be the front of the array
    printf("Successfully set currentPos to beginning.");
    if(((currentPos)->next) == NULL){ //Checks whether currentPos points to an empty list
        double requestMemForHead = MAX_MEMORY-size; //calculates the amount of memory requested
        if(size<requestMemForHead){ //Is the memory requested less than the memory available?
            (currentPos)->free_m = 0; //sets the free_m variable to 0 to indicate that the memory is no longer free (if it is available to allocate)
            void* currentMemDress = currentPos; //sets the current memory address to the current position of the list

            //checks whether allocation can proceed based on current allocation and request
            double requestMemLeftForAlloc = MAX_MEMORY-sizeOfMemHead;
            if(requestMemLeftForAlloc>sizeOfMemHead){
                struct memHead* newMemoryLocation = (memHead*) currentMemDress + (int) sizeOfMemHead + size; //tracks memory address and metadata
                newMemoryLocation->sizeOfMem = MAX_MEMORY - 2*sizeOfMemHead - size; //sets sizeOfMem to hold requested amount plus some
                newMemoryLocation->free_m = 0; //sets the free_m variable to 0 to indicate that the memory is not free
                newMemoryLocation->next = currentPos; //sets the next pointer to original position (beginning of array)
                currentPos->next = newMemoryLocation; //sets the next pointer of the previous location to the new memory location
                currentPos->sizeOfMem = size; //sets the sizeOfMem of the current position to the size requested
            } else {
                currentPos->next = currentPos;
                currentPos->sizeOfMem = MAX_MEMORY-sizeOfMemHead;
            }
            return(currentPos+1); //returns the address of the allocated memory
            }
        else {
            printf("Error: Not enough memory available to allocate. Here's where it failed: File %s: Line %d: \n", file, line); //if there is not enough memory available, throw error.
            return NULL;
        }
    }
    if ((currentPos) != NULL){ //if malloc was already run, skip initialization and iterate through the array to find an empty chunk
        while ((currentPos) != NULL) {
            if (((currentPos)->free_m) && ((currentPos)->sizeOfMem) >= size) {
                return currentPos;
            } else if (currentPos->next = currentPos){
                printf("Error: Not enough memory available to allocate. There are no free chunks available.\n");
                return NULL;
            }
            currentPos = currentPos->next; //found a node, set currentPos to it
            currentPos->free_m = 0; //once found, set the free_m variable to 0 to indicate that the memory is no longer free (if it is available to allocate)
        }
    }

    if((((currentPos)->sizeOfMem) - size) > sizeOfMemHead) {
        char* currentMemDress = (char*)currentPos;
        struct memHead* naeMemoryLocation = (memHead*) currentMemDress + sizeOfMemHead + size;
        naeMemoryLocation->sizeOfMem = currentPos->sizeOfMem - sizeOfMemHead - size;
        naeMemoryLocation->free_m = 0;
        naeMemoryLocation->next = currentPos->next;
        currentPos->next = naeMemoryLocation;
        currentPos->sizeOfMem = size;
    }

    void* dataAddress = (currentPos+1);
    void* headerAddress = currentPos;
    printf("Data address: %p\n", dataAddress);
    printf("Header address: %p\n", headerAddress);
    return(dataAddress);

}

void myfree(void *pnt, char *file, int line){
    if (!pnt) {
        if(pnt >= beginning + MAX_MEMORY){
            printf("Error: Cannot free memory that is not within the confines of the array. Here's where it failed: Your pointer: %p\n File: %s\n Line: %d\n", pnt, file, line);
            return;
        } else {
            printf("Error: Cannot free a null pointer. Here's where it failed: Your pointer: %p\n File: %s\n Line: %d\n", pnt, file, line);
            return;
        }
    }

    memHead* preBAddress = (memHead*)pnt-sizeOfMemHead;
        if(preBAddress->free_m == 1){
            printf("Error: Cannot free memory. Either invalid pointer or it was already freed. Here's where it failed: Your pointer: %p\n File: %s\n Line: %d\n", pnt, file, line);
            return;
        } else if((preBAddress)->free_m = 0){
            preBAddress->free_m = 1;
            printf("Memory freed successfully.\n");
            return;
        }
        //we're coalescing two blocks. (left -> right)
        memHead* postBAddress = preBAddress->next;
        if(postBAddress->free_m == 1){
            printf("Found an available free block. Checking where it's located.\n");
            if(postBAddress == beginning){
                printf("This wasn't supposed to happen. Either you haven't run malloc yet or this array isn't correct.\n"); //something got borked.
                return;
            } else if(postBAddress != beginning) {
                printf("Found blocks at address %p and address %p...\n", preBAddress, postBAddress);
                preBAddress->sizeOfMem = preBAddress->sizeOfMem + sizeOfMemHead + postBAddress->sizeOfMem; // adds the size of the metadata and the size of the block to the sizeOfMem of the preBAddress block, effectively combining the two blocks.
                preBAddress->next = postBAddress->next; //sets the next pointer of the new block to the location after the original postBAddress block.
                postBAddress = NULL; //nulls the block as it technically is part of preBAddress now.
                printf("Blocks coalesced successfully. Block address is %p.\n", preBAddress); //specifies the block addresses
                return;
            }

        }
        // now we check whether there are blocks to the left that are free and can be coalesced. (right -> left)
        memHead* currentPos = beginning;
        while(currentPos != NULL && !(currentPos->next == preBAddress && currentPos->free_m == 1 && currentPos != beginning)) {
            if (currentPos->next == beginning) { //checks whether the next block is the beginning of the array
                printf("We're at the last bit. Whoops.");
                return;
            }
            currentPos = currentPos->next; //sets the current position to the next block
        }
        printf("Found a free block to the left of the block you're trying to free. Coalescing blocks...\n");
        currentPos->sizeOfMem = currentPos->sizeOfMem + sizeOfMemHead + preBAddress->sizeOfMem; // adds the size of the metadata and the size of the block to the sizeOfMem of the preBAddress block, effectively combining the two blocks.
        currentPos->next = preBAddress->next; //sets the next pointer of the new block to the location after the original postBAddress block.
        preBAddress = NULL; //nulls the block as it technically is part of preBAddress now.
        printf("Blocks coalesced successfully. Block address is %p.\n", currentPos); //specifies the block addresses

};
```

And this is my header file:

```
#ifndef MALLOC_H
#define MALLOC_H
#include <stddef.h>

void *mymalloc(size_t size, char *file, int line);
void myfree(void *pnt, char *file, int line);

#define MAX_MEMORY 4096

typedef struct memHead {
    int sizeOfMem;
    int free_m;
    struct memHead* next;
}memHead;

#define malloc(s) mymalloc(s, __FILE__, __LINE__)
#define free(p) myfree(p, __FILE__, __LINE__)

#define sizeOfMemHead sizeof(struct memHead)
#endif
```

For example, I attempt to use malloc like so:

```
for(int i=0;i<120;i++){
    char *p = malloc(1);
    free(p);
}
```

My output is:

```
mymalloc called
Requested working bytes (reading MAX_MEMORY): 4096 bytes
Segmentation fault
```

It doesn't manage to assign the pointer to the beginning of the array. Am I doing something wrong? I've set a printf statement to the point after memHead* currentPos is meant to be assigned the value of beginning, but it never gets to that point so I'm sure the issue lies within `memHead* currentPos = beginning;`.

I've attempted to change the type of the memory array to char to no avail as well.

Comment: `} else if (currentPos->next = currentPos){` looks highly suspicious... Haven't read all the code and comments 'cuz I don't have all day... Comments should say "why" not "what"... And variable names needed be entire chapters in themselves... Brevity is the soul of wit...

Comment: Quote: `newMemoryLocation->free_m = 0; //sets the free_m variable to 1 to...` The trouble with "what" comments... Is the code wrong, or is the comment wrong?

Comment: Can you add `myfree` so we can try to compile this ourselves?

Comment: I added myfree to it. I also fixed the comment, the comment was definitely wrong. I'll cut down the comments too.

Comment: I added some `printf` statements. The crash is happening in `myfree()`, not `mymalloc()`.

Comment: If you're advanced enough to try to implement your own allocator, surely you know how to use a debugger.

Comment: Do you really think that we are a free debugging service? Too much code. Run it in the debugger line by line and see if it does what you think it does.. All of us do it on daily basis.

Comment: I don't see `static double memory[MAX_MEMORY]` being initialized to anything useful before being used.